# How to deal (if at all) with poorly translated ads?

Tags: discussion, advertising

I recently came across this poorly translated advertisement for Microsoft Azure on Stack Overflow.

[image: Microsoft Azure ad]

I strongly believe the original phrase `Code in..` was incorrectly auto-translated with `Codieren Sie in..` since a real person capable of the German language wouldn't have translated it with `Codieren`.

What would be the procedure to deal with these mishaps or should they be left unattended?

Comment: Was it really auto-translated? Anyway, a more correct phrase would be _“Programmieren Sie in Node.js, Java, Python und anderen Open-Source-Sprachen”_ (note the hyphens). Alternatively _“Schreiben Sie Code in Node.js [etc.]”_. The rest is correct.

Comment: Yeah, don't get me started on Quora's auto translation of questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The content of the advertisement is up to the advertiser, not Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange, as long as it's not inappropriate content for Stack Overflow.

As such, you could try to contact the advertiser.

Since I don't think typing errors are inappropriate, I don't think you need to raise it here.

Note that if it annoys you, you can dismiss this specific ad.

<sub>If anything, this ad might be informative of the quality of translations by the Azure Translator Text API</sub>